# How to dismiss the keyboard from the view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created the textfield programmatically for getting the value in it. Once i got the value in the textfield i wanted to dismiss the keyboard.

Could anyone help me in this with sample code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you *are* asking about iOS' keyboard, then you can do this:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

When a `UITextField` gains focus, it is said to have "gained first responder status", meaning that it is the first `UIResponder` in the responder *chain*. What this means to you is that when you send the `resignFirstResponder` message to a `UIResponder`, the receiver will be popped off the responder chain and the next responder in the chain will gain first responder status.

Answer (score 2):

```
[inputView resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a text field delegate method that would send `resignFirstResponder` message to text field in question when "return" button is pressed:

```
// in some method
[myTextField setDelegate:self];

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```

This code is off top of my head so doublecheck the delegate method title.

Answer (score 0):

have one button Action

```
 UIButton *keyboard=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
keyboard.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,320,460);
[keyboard addTarget:self action:@selector(keyDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:keyboard];
```

in button action write this code

```
 -(void)keyDown{

[textfield resignFirstResponder];
```

}