# Hiding the keyboard when application returns from suspension

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, persistence

I have an application where the login screen moves the username/password fields up by resizing the main view when the keyboard is shown.

The problem is that if I suspend the app (clicking the home button) while the keyboard is visible and then bring the application back, it will "reset" the view size (as per the NIB), but the keyboard will still be visible, meaning that part of the "form" becomes hidden by the keyboard.

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to either hide the keyboard whenever the application returns from a suspended state (I know `applicationDidBecomeActive` gets called on my app delegate), or make sure that the view remains resized?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dismiss the keyboard from the view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014674/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-from-the-view)

Comment: Don't think it's a duplicate. Calling `resignFirstResponder` might do it if the control was returned to the app and something like `viewWillAppear` was called. If any method of my viewcontroller was called when the app comes back from suspension, `resignFirstResponder` could work. What I'm missing is a way to get notified, within the context of the controller, that the app is back from suspension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification (via `addObserver:selector:name:object:` selector of `NSNotificationCenter`) and call `[element resignFirstResponder]`.

I'm not sure whether it'll go down smoothly since the keyboard always animates when hiding, but at least it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be able to achieve this using [`NSNotificationCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In your view controller, in viewWillAppear call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWasResumed) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

and implement a method:

```
-(void) appWasResumed
{
    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    //If you are changing positions of items, you might want to do that here too.
}
```

and I think the rest should be handled automatically.

If it's not handled automatically try adding this to your AppDelegate on `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

I've not used NSNotificationCenter a lot, so some of the syntax may be wrong. Check out the link I provided at the top for confirmation.